# Adding cluster to Opscenter fails intermittently due to Enterprise functionality: False

Tags: opscenter, datastax-enterprise

I am working with a OpsCenter 5.1.1 installation, while trying to add an existing DSE 4.6.5 cluster containing 5 nodes via the API. The options passed set the storage_cassandra variables for storing data on a separate cluster.

Intermittently this will fail and return a Time out with the following in the logs:

```
2015-06-04 21:00:10+0000 [dse_test]  INFO: Enterprise functionality: False
2015-06-04 21:00:10+0000 [dse_test]  INFO: OpsCenter shutting down.
2015-06-04 21:00:10+0000 [dse_test]  INFO: Stopping repair service
2015-06-04 21:00:10+0000 []  INFO: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-06-04 21:00:10+0000 [] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/opt/iot-packages/datastax_opscenter/5.1.1/opscenter-5.1.1/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 361, in callback
            self._startRunCallbacks(result)
          File "/opt/iot-packages/datastax_opscenter/5.1.1/opscenter-5.1.1/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 455, in _startRunCallbacks
            self._runCallbacks()
          File "/opt/iot-packages/datastax_opscenter/5.1.1/opscenter-5.1.1/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 542, in _runCallbacks
            current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
          File "/opt/iot-packages/datastax_opscenter/5.1.1/opscenter-5.1.1/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1076, in gotResult
            _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/opt/iot-packages/datastax_opscenter/5.1.1/opscenter-5.1.1/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send(result)
          File "build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/ClusterServices.py", line 475, in waitForStartup

        exceptions.Exception: Storing data in a separate cluster is only supported when managing DSE clusters.
```

However, trying again using the same commands will succeed on the next attempt with the following difference in the opscenter log:

> Enterprise functionality: True

What determines the enterprise functionality being set and how can I make sure it is consistent?

Comment: Enterprise functionality may be a red herring here. It basically means opsc detected that you are running DSE, not open source c*.

Comment: Anything in your agent logs?

Comment: There is nothing in the agent logs when it fails, just the opscenter log itself. How does enterprise functionality get determined, it should always be true, yet is failing randomly.